# Angular : SVG directives inside ng-repeat renders incorrectly

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display an SVG (rendered inside a directive) twice on my page, with different values. The SVG-directive sits within an ng-repeat.

This is the relevant html :

```
<div ng-repeat="sprint in project.sprintinfo"
...//other repeat stuff
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <circlesvg
                       percentages="sprint.percentages"
                       total="sprint.total"
                       colors="['#d667cd','#3c5d9b','#5acd2d']"
                       size="80"
                       id="sprint.id">
            </circlesvg>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Then I use raphael.js in my directive : (relevant raphael)

```
angular.module('timeAppApp')
.directive('circlesvg', [function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            percentages: '=',
            total: '=',
            colors : '=',
            //lineair : '=',
            size: '=',
            id: '='
        },
        template: '<div id="{{id}}"></div>', //dynamically bind id to the template
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
         // function draw() {

            scope.id = 'item' + scope.id++; //change id for next drawing round

              ...//code to draw my SVG

                  (function (raphael) {

                  var size = scope.size;
                  var values = scope.percentages;
                  if(typeof(values)=="undefined") {
                      console.log("nothing to draw here.");
                      return;
                  }

                  var r = raphael("{{id}}", size, size); //get id for raphael to draw his SVG
                  var s = size / 2;
                  r.pieChart(s, s, s, values, "#fff");
                  var c = s - (s * 0.15);
                  r.circle(s, s, c).attr({fill: 'white'});
                  var text = scope.total;
                  r.text(s, s, text).attr({'font-size': 25});


              })(Raphael.ninja());
```

Now the problem is: both SVG's are being drawn, with the corresponding correct values BUT they are both drawn inside the first div.

The second div is created, but empty. This looks like this in the browser : [image: double SVG]

Here you see a div called "item9" with 2(!) SVG's rendered in it.
A bit further down we find :[image: empty div]
Where you can see the second div called "item13", but which is empty.

So the question is : what do I need to do, to make the second SVG render inside the second div.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have a template, and referencing the string `{{id}}` to give you unexpected results. I would just use the DOM element created by Angular for the directive.

```
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            el[0].setAttribute('id','item' + scope.id++);

           (function (raphael) {
                  var r = raphael(el[0], size, size);
           })(Raphael.ninja());
```

The above should add an attribute ID to `circlesvg` and create one SVG as a child.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to say thanks but still...thanks! :D I still have no idea why my code wouldn't work, but this works like a charm. I didn't know a template was optional. Thanks for the info and the help.